# How to use `ioredis` to connect to Redis instance (AWS elasticcache) across ssh tunnel with SSL?

Tags: ssl, redis, ssh-tunnel, node-redis

This seems to be something about `ioredis` and its support for TLS.  This is all on a mac, Catalina, etc.

I have an elasticcache Redis instance running, inside a VPC.  I tunnel to it with ssh,

```
ssh -L 6379:clustercfg.my-test-redis.amazonaws.com:6379 -N MyEC2
```

The following doesn't work with `node 12.9`, `ioredis 4.19.4`

```
> const Redis = require("ioredis");
> const redis = new Redis('rediss://127.0.0.1:6379');

[ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error [ERR_TLS_CERT_ALTNAME_INVALID]: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: IP: 127.0.0.1 is not in the cert's list: 
    at Object.checkServerIdentity (tls.js:287:12)
    <repeated ... many times>
```

This doesn't work either:

```
> const Redis = require("ioredis");
> const redis = new Redis('redis://127.0.0.1:6379');
> redis.status
'connect'
> redis.set('fooo','barr').then(console.log).catch(console.error)
Promise { <pending> }
> redis.status
'connect'
```

Is there a way to let me do this with `ioredis`?    This is just for debugging.  If the first form is correct, is there a setting to allow "non-strict" validation of the cert or something?

This works (on a mac)

```
% openssl s_client -connect localhost:6379
set "fred" "Mary"
+OK
get "fred"
$4
Mary
```

This works (with redis installed via pip3)

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import redis
r = redis.Redis(host='127.0.0.1', ssl=True, port=6379)
r.set('foo', 'bar')
print(r.get('foo'))
```

Comment: And I think the answer may be `process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0';` but I'm still curious if there is a specific configuration setting in ioredis versus doing this globally.  (That does work.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I wouldn't recommend this for production, you said this was for debugging.

You need to disable the server identity check. You can do that by overriding the function in the configuration with a noop:

```js
const Redis = require("ioredis");
const redis = new Redis('rediss://127.0.0.1:6379', {
  tls: {
    checkServerIdentity: () => undefined,
  }
});
```